# Is it possible to showing unselected options in text box through jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Is it possible to showing selected value from another text box & unselected options to another text box.

For example , I have 2 text boxes & one select box with `options(location_1,location_2,location_3)`.

So when i select option `location_2` or any then selected option value will be showing in `text_box_1` & remaining unselected options `(location_1,location_3)` that value will be appearing into another text box is `text_box_2`.

I have tried to do following ways but only get select option value not unselect.

HTML

```
<select name="pd_location[]" class="form-control">
    <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
    <option value="1">Location One</option>
    <option value="2">Location Two</option>   
    <option value="3">Location Three</option>   
    <option value="4">Location Four</option>   
</select>
```

Jquery

```
 $(document).on('change', '.select_location', function() {
        var get_sel_option = $(this).attr("selected_val");
        var index=     $(".select_location").prop('selectedIndex');

        if(index){
            var sel_option_test=   $('.select_location option ').attr("selected","selected");  
        }

     });
```

How could i get unselect option values ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.map()` to get all the options not selected.

> Description: Translate all items in an array or object to new array of
>   items.

```js
$('select[name="pd_location[]"]').on("change", function() {
    $('.text_box').val('');
    var selected = this.value;
    if( selected ) {
        $('#text_box_1').val( selected );
        var unselected = $(this).find('option:not(:first):not(:selected)').map(function() { return this.value; }).get().join(",");
        $('#text_box_2').val( unselected );
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="pd_location[]" class="form-control">
    <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
    <option value="1">Location One</option>
    <option value="2">Location Two</option>   
    <option value="3">Location Three</option>   
    <option value="4">Location Four</option>   
</select>
<input name="text_box_1" id="text_box_1" class="text_box">
<input name="text_box_2" id="text_box_2" class="text_box">
```